# Keep receiving error code CS0165

Tags: c#

I keep getting the aggravated CS0165 error code. I have re-written this several times and even googled the issues. I cannot resolve this, it is for a college assignment that is now 2 days late. Can anyone please help. Would appreciate. This is the code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Text;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string InputPath = @"C:\Users\....\Desktop\CP Class\Assignment 2\Asgn2InputFile.txt";
        string OutputPath = @"C:\Users\....\Desktop\CP Class\Assignment 2\Payroll.txt";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(InputPath))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(OutputPath))
        {
            // input line
            string InputLine;

            // input fields
            string First;
            string Last;
            int Hours;
            int OverT;
            double Pay;

            // output fields
            double Earnings;
            double Gross;

            //
            sw.Write("NAME".PadRight(11));
            sw.Write("HOURS WORKED ".PadRight(23));
            sw.Write("PAY RATE".PadRight(20));
            sw.Write("OVERTIME".PadRight(27));
            sw.WriteLine();

            while ((InputLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)

            //  parse input line
            First = InputLine.Substring(0, 5);
            Last = InputLine.Substring(0, 11);
            Pay = double.Parse(InputLine.Substring(31, 5));
            Hours = int.Parse(InputLine.Substring(16, 2));
            OverT = int.Parse(InputLine.Substring(29, 1));

            // 
            Earnings = (Hours * Pay);
            Gross = Earnings + (OverT * (Pay * 1.5));
            sw.Write(First.PadRight(11)); [[ Error Code occurs here ]]
            sw.WriteLine(Last.PadRight(11));

            //
            sw.Write(Earnings.ToString().PadLeft(10) + " @ " + Gross.ToString("C").PadRight(9));
            sw.WriteLine(Earnings.ToString("C").PadLeft(17));
            sw.WriteLine();
            //Total += Earnings;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error **CS0165** is because you are using variables that are not initialized....

the reason is the omitting of the **{ }** here

```
while ((InputLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
```

which means, the while loop has as scope something else as what you need

in fact your code is equivalent to:

```
while ((InputLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null){
      First = InputLine.Substring(0, 5);
}
```

leaving the rest uninitialized

Answer (score 1):

Because your `while` loop doesn't have any braces to block the code it contains, it only takes the first line of code beneath as the content. Because the compiler cannot guarantee that line will run, the variable `First` might not be initialised.

So instead of doing this:

```
while (something)
DoSomething();
DoSomethingElse();
```

You should write:

```
while (something)
{
    DoSomething();
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in your code

1. While loop braces are missing
2. You have declared your variables so far away from its first use and made it so long that it is difficult to see issues

Look at the below code which I think is what you want

```
using System;
using System.IO;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Text;
//using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            string InputPath = @"C:\Users\....\Desktop\CP Class\Assignment 2\Asgn2InputFile.txt";
            string OutputPath = @"C:\Users\....\Desktop\CP Class\Assignment 2\Payroll.txt";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(InputPath))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(OutputPath)) {

                sw.Write("NAME".PadRight(11));
                sw.Write("HOURS WORKED ".PadRight(23));
                sw.Write("PAY RATE".PadRight(20));
                sw.Write("OVERTIME".PadRight(27));
                sw.WriteLine();

                // input line
                string InputLine;
                while ((InputLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {

                    //  parse input line
                    var First = InputLine.Substring(0, 5);
                    var Last = InputLine.Substring(0, 11);
                    var Pay = double.Parse(InputLine.Substring(31, 5));
                    var Hours = int.Parse(InputLine.Substring(16, 2));
                    var OverT = int.Parse(InputLine.Substring(29, 1));

                    // 
                    var Earnings = (Hours * Pay);
                    var Gross = Earnings + (OverT * (Pay * 1.5));
                    sw.Write(First.PadRight(11)); //Error Code occurs here
                    sw.WriteLine(Last.PadRight(11));

                    //
                    sw.Write(Earnings.ToString().PadLeft(10) + " @ " + Gross.ToString("C").PadRight(9));
                    sw.WriteLine(Earnings.ToString("C").PadLeft(17));
                    sw.WriteLine();
                    //Total += Earnings;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```